# how do you split a string with a string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, token

I would like to split a string into a String[] using a String as a delimiter.

```
String delimit = "[break]";
String[] tokens = myString.Split(delimit);
```

But the method above only works with a char as a delimiter.

Any takers?

Comment: I have allways wondered that too. So instead of using the string.split() I have falled back to the old Visula Basic Split function instead. Where you do MyArray=split(TheString,Delimiter). Its there and easy to use when you are programming vb.net so I have never tried to investigate this furter. So it will be interresting to read the answers here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this:

```
mystring.Split(new string[] { delimit }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

For some reason, the only overloads of [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) that take a string take it as an array, along with a `StringSplitOptions`.
I have no idea why there isn't a `string.Split(params string[])` overload.

Comment: Great answer. Worked first time. =)

Comment: Actually, there is no `String.Split(char)` overload either. There is however a `String.Split(params char[])` overload, and that's what allows you to call it with a single `char`. The reason there is no `String.Split(params string[])` overload is because you cannot have two params overloads like that because calling `String.Split()` without parameters would be ambiguous between the two.

Comment: @Sven: There is nothing wrong with having two `params` overloads.  If you call it without any parameters, you get an error on the callsite. (I tried it) For `Split`, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: However, you're right that I should have said `params string[]`.

Comment: Yes, but in this case String.Split() is explicitly allowed (it means that whitespace characters are the delimiters). If both a `params char[]` and a `params string[]` overload existed you could no longer make that call, and the only way to get that behaviour would be `String.Split((char[])null)` or `String.Split(new char[0])`, neither of which is particularly elegant. I suspect that is the reason a `params string[]` overload was not provided.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer to use something like this, since regex has that split:

```
public static string[] Split(this string input, string delimit)
{
  return Regex.Split(input, delimit);
}
```

Comment: +1 to be on the safe side I suggest using `Regex.Escape(delimit)` to escape any metacharacters that might be part of the delimiter.

Comment: Since the string isn't really a regex, there's no point in invoking the regex parser.

Comment: `Regex.Split` parses the input first, which is expensive, and then splits the output of the **matches**

Comment: @Munim True, Regex is working with matching groups, but OP is asking about "easy" way, not "fastest" way. Seems easy enough for me.

Comment: I agree with you @Victor. This is the easiest but the slowest :) Cheers