# Why doesn't Split from System.String accept string as an overload?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t there a string.Split(string) overload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302564/why-isnt-there-a-string-splitstring-overload)

There are several overloads but not one that allows sending a string. Which is the very often used by developers, at least by my team.

```
string[] x = "abc|||dev".Split("|||");
```

Why?..

---

Please, I am not asking How to do split passing string.

Answer (score 3):

```
x.Split(new String[] { "|||" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Regex.Split(x, @"([a-zA-Z]+)\|\|\|([a-zA-Z]+)");

public static class StringExtensions()
{
    public static String[] Split(this String s, String delimiter)
    {        
        return s.Split(new String[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```

Comment: Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Comment: As I said, I'm aware of the overloads. My question is why not accepting the plain string. If there is any idea behind that...

Comment: This has always annoyed me too.  I suppose you could add it as an extension method.

Comment: Please read my question...

Comment: It might have been an oversight, as for why Microsoft does not provide one, Eric Lippert wrote a blog post about "Why did you not implement function X", and the answer was that there is a lot of organizational overhead to make library changes for something that can simply be solved by writing it yourself.  (Things like documentation, translations, unit-tests, deployment, QA, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain you why. Probably for convenience as array parameters will be internally iterated to produce splits.

Comment: Matthew, so probably someone missed implementing that in the first place? sounds possible but weird

Comment: Happens all the time, might be why extension methods were born.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say why it isn't included but if you do a lot of string-splitting then an extension-method would be in order to help you with your favorite overload.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] x = "abc|||dev".Split("|||");
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string[] Split(this string str, string separator)
    {
        return str.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just going to write this!

Comment: How about `        public static string[] Split(this string str, params string[] separators)
        {
            return str.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        }
`?