# Implicit conversion from char to char[] in F#?

Tags: f#

Why does String.Split accept a char although it requires a char[]

```
let c = '.' // char
"aa.bb".Split(c) // works! although Split requires char[]
```

An implicit type conversion from char to char[] does not explain it, as this shows:

```
let f (cs : char[]) = ()

f('a') // error: expected char[]
```

Comment: I think because it actually takes a C# `params char[]` which has a conversion.  Some more detail here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302564/why-isnt-there-a-string-splitstring-overload

Comment: you are right! if you want to post it as answer, i mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.Split` doesn't quite take a `char[]` as an argument.  It actually takes a `params char[]`.  As a result, the compiler does some magic and the call is possible with just a single `char`.